# Pivot Table with Runtime Error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, vba

I copied a template to create a pivot table but adjusted it for a dynamic range due to reports being different in sizes at work. I keep getting Runtime Error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument as an error however when trying to create the pivot table from the pivot cache.

Can anyone please assist?

Thanks,

```vb
    Dim sht As Worksheet   
    Dim pvtCache As PivotCache   
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim StartPvt As String  
    Dim SrcData As Range
    
   'Determine the data range you want to pivot
    Set SrcData = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    'ActiveSheet.Name & "!" &
    'Range("A1:R100").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    
    'Create a new worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets.Add
    With sht
        .Name = "Payments Balancing"
    End With
    
    'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
    StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" &
    sht.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    
    'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
    Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                     SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                     SourceData:=SrcData)
    
    'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                        TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
                        TableName:="PivotTable1")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Think your `StartPvt` variable needs some single quotes. `"'" & sht.Name & "'!" &
sht.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`

Comment: `TableDestination` accepts a Range argument, so you can also use `TableDestination:=sht.Range("A1")`